# Is a networking loop considered a DoS attack?

Tags: networking, loop, ddos

Is a networking loop considered a DoS attack?

I watched this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzLdfYF7Cs4) and at `1:20`:

The author says that a network loop, could be a DoS in a network?

Comment: As aircraft has explained below a denial of service attack is just a term used, when  for instance, your network is being flooded and thereby is not available. The author in the video describes a normal loop in a network or configuration error as a DoS, as it floods the network and makes it unavailable, typically because it uses up all resources on switches and routers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the network manager does something by mistake it's just pilot error; if I sneak into your building and do something to make trouble for you on purpose, it's an attack.

If the attack is designed so that you can't use your own things, it's a denial of service attack.  Advertising film stars arriving at your building, for example, or throwing marbles down your stairs.

If the attack is designed to permanently break your things, it's a destructive attack, not denial of service.

The most common that people talk about in networking are remote denial of service attacks, often distributed, as these are specially interesting.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) we can know the definition:

> In computing, a denial-of-service attack (DoS attack) is a cyber-attack in which the perpetrator seeks to make a machine or network resource unavailable to its intended users by temporarily or indefinitely disrupting services of a host connected to the Internet. Denial of service is typically accomplished by flooding the targeted machine or resource with superfluous requests in an attempt to overload systems and prevent some or all legitimate requests from being fulfilled.[1]
>
> In a distributed denial-of-service attack (DDoS attack), the incoming traffic flooding the victim originates from many different sources. This effectively makes it impossible to stop the attack simply by blocking a single source.

I don't think the simple circuits is Denial of service but there are full of data circulate in the circuits, so that the server in the circuits can not provide available services to the network.

Comment: I accidentally corrected DoS to DDoS in the question, i corrected in back to DoS as the difference is quite big.